# One page prev/next navigation based on list/anchor links

Tags: jquery

After your finished laughing at my attempt to modify some jQuery could someone help me with:

http://goo.gl/MNhqq8

What I would like to happen is:

To be left with 2 visible buttons PREV/NEXT so hide all the other li's.
Obviously the PREV button will work and go to the previous anchor and NEXT going to the next anchor.

Or am I going about this the completely wrong way... open to better suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only modified a few parts:

First, keep only 2 buttons:

```
<li><a href="#prev" class="scroll">PREV</a></li>
<li><a href="#next" class="scroll">NEXT</a></li>
```

Next, keep track of the different anchors, and which one is active:

```
var anchors = ['anchortop', 'anchorone', 'anchortwo', 'anchorthree', 'anchorfour', 'anchorfive'];
var currentIdx = 0;
```

Finally, either decrement or increment the currentIdx depending on which button was clicked and which section we are at:

```
var full_url = this.href,
    parts = full_url.split('#'),
    btn = parts[1];

if (btn == 'prev' && currentIdx > 0) {
    currentIdx--;
} else if (btn == 'next' && currentIdx < anchors.length - 1) {
    currentIdx++;
}

var trgt = anchors[currentIdx],
    target_offset = $('#' + trgt).offset(),
    target_top = target_offset.top;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqP25/13/)